# Sidekiq is jacking up my performance monitoring in New Relic

Tags: ruby, heroku, newrelic, sidekiq

Help! I recently started implementing Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) in my Ruby app. I haven't noticed a specific performance drop. However in New Relic, on my monitoring page, it seems there is an added impact to my overview graph where it appears DB time is just overtaking the whole stack of app response time layers.

Clarification: After my last deploy, all of a sudden my overview graph shows no Ruby time and a whole bunch of database time, but my database use hasn't changed and I'm sure my application is serving web requests. What could cause that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common cause of this issue is that background jobs which are not directly servicing web requests (e.g. Resque, Sidekiq, DelayedJob, or other manually instrumented scripts like rake tasks) are being instrumented by the New Relic agent with the same application name as a web application. When this happens, the database time used by the background task is being combined with the metrics from the web application.

The easiest solution is usually to separate out background tasks from your main application by having them report in under a different application name. You can do this by setting the `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME` enviroment variable to a custom application name when starting your background workers.

On Heroku, you can do this by prepending `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME='<your name> (background)'` onto the command used to start your background workers in your Procfile. In other environments, you can similarly edit the command used to start your background workers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think New Relic works with SideKiq.

Comment: Can you provide a citation, please? Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: It works for me (but took a bit of time to get started for some reason).